# Q_PROPERTY usage with void * properties

Tags: c++, qt, properties, activex

I'm trying to implement a `void *` property in an ActiveX component as described below.

```
class AxClass : public QWidget, public QAxBindable
{
   Q_OBJECT
   Q_PROPERTY(void * ptr READ getPtr WRITE setPtr)

   public:
     void * getPtr() const { return _ptr; }
     void setPtr(void * ptr) { _ptr = ptr; }
     .
     .
     .
   private:
     void * _ptr;
};
```

However, Qt seems to ignore the property (it does not show up when I query AxClass's MetaObject about its properties). I've experimented with the type and come to the following conclusion: Pointers simply don't work in my scenario. A `QString *` also yields an ignored property, whilst a regular `QString` works as expected (the property shows when querying the meta object).

I've been struggling for days, so any help to bring closure to this would be greatly appreciated, whether I can or cannot use this approach.

Comment: Using Qt 4.7.3. As far as I know, void * should be supported without resorting to Q_DECLARE_METATYPE et al.

Comment: How do you query properties?

Comment: I don't have the exact code in front of me (not working at the moment), but it's in the Qt 4 docs. I use the QMetaObject info to get the number of properties and iterate through them to get their names.

Comment: May be a bug in Qt, because the [following code](http://pastebin.com/W9LAdzxG) works with Qt 4.8.2 as expected with your property being last in the list.

Comment: The actual `.dll` containing the code seems to not be loaded at program launch. Sorry if this is mistaken. I'm very hazy as to how all this works behind my back. Anyway, it seems to be loaded when the class is instantiated(via a `QAxFactory` as far as I can tell). Does anybody have an idea if this matters?